Using gSoap to fetch a file from an Interplay Web Services instance
I plan to use gSoap in my project to fetch a file (located at an endpoint + URI) from an Interplay Web Services instance. Is there a best practice to go about this? I notice there are several plugins and imports offered by gSoap that I can include in my project, but I'm not sure which is the best choice to accomplish this.
Thanks!

After looking into the documentation for my Interplay Web Services instance, it seems like GetLatest is the correct option, where an endpoint and URI are provided and the file (if it exists) is returned as a binary representation:

The GetLatest operation is used to get the latest version of a non-Avid asset or to get the AAF of an Avid asset.

